# angular 4.1.0 compatibility

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am currently using angular 2.0.0-rc.4. I would like to convert it to 4.1.0.
**Is 2.0.0-rc.4  compatible with 4.1.0?** I read in [this](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html) document that it is backwards compatible with 2.x.x , Is 2.0.0-rc.4 includes in 2.x.x?

Comment: You should check the changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

You will need some reorganizing, not big changes for example after 4.0 template is no more available you need to use ng-template instead.For animations you need  "@angular/animations": "4.1.0" this package and finally you can import it like this 
    `import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` i guess thats all you need to know at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Angular upgrade guide App available which I can recommend.

Have a look at [AngularUpgradeApp](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)

It' explains for a wide range of `fromVersions` what to do to get on the required `toVersion`